# How can I solve this error Error in FUN(X[[i]], ...)?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I wanna have a scatterplot and I'm inserting this

```
ggplot(x, aes(x = pressure, y = Weight)) + geom_point()
```

but I'm getting this error message:

> Error in FUN(X[[i]], ...) : object 'Weight' not found

My data:

```
x=data.frame(pressure=c(11.2,11.5,11,11.1,13,14),weight=c(70,75,67,73,100,120))
```

Comment: It should be `y = weight` (lowercase).

Answer (score 2):

Error messages in R are usually accompanied by the innermost call that triggered the error (the general format is “Error in *‹innermost call›*: *‹message›*”). Unfortunately this innermost call is usually not informative for the end user (= you) because it is unrelated to *your* function call. It requires you to know the internals of the function you’re using.

When using third-party libraries, you should therefore initially ignore that part of the error message and focus on the second part:

> object 'Weight' not found my data:

This clearly states what the problem is: You’re trying to access an object named `Weight`, and no such object was found. This is, 90% of the time, a simple spelling error.

As noted in the comments, the correct spelling of your variable should be lower-case `weight`.